# Apply functon with a condition on the first row

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert data. 
For instance, I would like to apply (lambda x: x+273.15) on each columns which contain °C data.

A set of data :

Before

```
TIME    Temp     Pressure
 s       °C        Pa
 0       20        10^5
 1       30        10^5
```

After

```
TIME    Temp     Pressure
 s       °C        Pa
 0      293.5        10^5
 1      303.5        10^5

Data=pd.DataFrame({'Time':['s',0.,1.],
               'Temp':['°C',20.,30.],
               'Pressure':['Pa',10^5,10^5]})
```

What would be the best solution ? 
I only managed to split the Dataframe into Dataframes with only one unit, work on each Dataframes and concatenate them all. 
I guess there is a better way to do this :o

I also tried this :

```
def test(x):
    try :
        x=x+273.15
    except:
        x
    return x

def C_to_K(Col):
    if Col[0]=='°C':
        Col=Col.map(lambda x: test(x))


Data=Data.apply(C_to_K,axis=0 )
```

EDIT : Using eumiro solution

```
import pandas as pd

Data=pd.DataFrame({'Time':['s',0.,1.],
                   'Temp':['°C',20.,30.],
                   'Pressure':['Pa',10^5,10^5]})

ListColName=[]
for ColName in Data.columns:
    ListColName.append(ColName)

ListUnit=[]
for Unit in Data.iloc[0]:
    ListUnit.append(Unit)

ListMetaData=[]
for i in range(len(ListColName)):
    tampo=ListColName[i]+" ["+ListUnit[i]+"]"
    ListMetaData.append(tampo)


Data.columns=ListMetaData
Data=Data.drop(Data.index[0])

for col in Data.columns[:]:
    if col.endswith('[°C]'):
        Data[col[:-5] + '[K]'] = Data[col] + 273.15
        Data=Data.drop(col,1)
```

Edit : Other solution if directly read from csv file

```
Data=pd.read_csv('Test.csv', header=[0,1])

for col in Data.columns[:]:
if col[1]=='°C':
    Data[col[0],'K'] = Data[col] + 273.15
    Data=Data.drop(col,1)
```

Comment: Why not just use `df.Temp = df.Temp + 273.15`?

Comment: @ Anton : It's just an example here. The real data could be in several unit (Fahrenheit, Kelvin etc...). So I need to check the unit first to know what function use.

Comment: Could you provide example with several units in `Temp` column?

Comment: Databis=pd.DataFrame({'Time':['s',0.,1.],
               'Temp':['°C',20.,30.],
               'Pressure':['Pa',10^5,10^5],
               'Tempbis':['K',300.,500.]}). It's not several units in the same column but several column in differents units.

Comment: how are you getting that dataframe? If you use `read_csv` you could pass for `header` two rows, then your units will be in 2nd level of header.

Comment: Yes thanks ! I don't think to use that >.<

Comment: You don't need to use drop in case you using `read_csv` with `header=[0,1]` because first row already read as header. Just delete that line

Comment: Consider to accept @eumiro or mine solution if any of them helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to store units in first row. You could do 2 level header for that and then operate with them as with usual numeric columns. First you need to do 2 level header, then drop 1st row and cast `reset_index` to make it from 0 (or you could omit that if you are fine with index starting from 1):

```
In [860]: Databis
Out[860]: 
  Pressure Temp Tempbis Time
0       Pa   °C       K    s
1       15   20     300    0
2       15   30     500    1


Databis.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(Databis.columns, Databis.iloc[0])))
Databis = Databis.drop(Databis.index[0]).reset_index(drop=True)

In [862]: Databis
Out[862]: 
  Pressure Temp Tempbis Time
        Pa   °C       K    s
0       15   20     300    0
1       15   30     500    1

Databis.Temp = Databis.Temp + 273.15

In [864]: Databis
Out[864]: 
  Pressure    Temp Tempbis Time
        Pa      °C       K    s
0       15  293.15     300    0
1       15  303.15     500    1
```

*Note: If you are reading dataframe with `read_csv` function you could pass `header=[0,1]`. Then you'll have 2 level header*

Answer (score 0):

Increasing a Celsius column by 273.15 (`x = x + 273.15`) makes it a Kelvin column without updating the description, so at some point your data is inconsistent.

The best solution is not to put units into the first row of real data at all. Can't you name your columns `Temp [°C]` or `Temp/°C` and test the name of the column?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time [s]':[0.,1.],
                   'Temp [°C]':[20.,30.],
                   'Pressure [Pa]':[10^5,10^5]})
for col in df.columns[:]:
    if col.endswith('[°C]'):
        df[col[:-5] + '[K]'] = df[col] + 273.15
```

`df` is now:

```
   Pressure [Pa]  Temp [°C]  Time [s]   Temp [K]
0             15         20         0     293.15
1             15         30         1     303.15
```

Comment: Yes I already think about this solution but I need something more powerfull.

Comment: @coolpix: Mixing metadata and data is not more powerful. It is more wrong.

Comment: I can't choose the input format. But maybe I could manage to modify the DataFrame to fit your example ?

Comment: @Coolpix - DataFrames are great for homogenous data, such as columns full of float values. Putting a string into the first row breaks the whole advantage of DataFrames. You even cannot add a number to the whole column.

Comment: I understand your point of view but it's not entirely true. I can add a number to the whole column using a function with exeption. I just need to know how to filter the column with a condition on the first row. However, I am trying your solution. I still have to fit the right format.